# Nokogiri HttParty Xpath Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nokogiri

I am working with a Eve Online request that returns XML. I am using HTTParty for the request, and I am trying to use Nokogiri to obtain attribute values for a specific element.

Here's an example of the response:

```
 <eveapi version="2"><currentTime>2012-10-19 22:41:56</currentTime><result><rowset  name="transactions" key="refID"  columns="date,refID,refTypeID,ownerName1,ownerID1,ownerName2,ownerID2,argName1,argID1,amount,balance,reason,taxReceiverID,taxAmount"><row date="2012-10-18 23:41:50" refID="232323" refTypeID="9" ownerName1="University of Caille" ownerID1="32232" ownerName2="name" ownerID2="34343" argName1="" argID1="0" amount="5000.00" balance="5000.00" reason="Starter fund" taxReceiverID="" taxAmount=""/></rowset></result><cachedUntil>2012-10-19 23:03:40</cachedUntil></eveapi>
```

I only need to access attributes for the element "row" and there can be many rows returned.

I read about XPath and, from what I understand, if I do the following it should return all rows: `doc.xpath('row')` however, it does not return anything.

Here's what I have so far:

```
options = {:keyID => 111111, :vCode => 'fddfdfdfdf'}
response = HTTParty.post('https://api.eveonline.com/char/WalletJournal.xml.aspx', :body => options)
doc = Nokogiri::XML(response.body)
doc.xpath('row').each do |r|

end
```

The loop is never executed.

What am I doing wrong?  I need to return all row elements and gain access to each of the row's attributes.

Here's the code I had before, which worked until I tried a different character and received a "cannot convert integer to string error":

```
options = {:keyID => 434343, :vCode => 'fdfdfdfdf'}
response = HTTParty.post('https://api.eveonline.com/char/WalletJournal.xml.aspx', :body => options)
data = response.parsed_response
data['eveapi']['result']['rowset']['row'].each do |t|
  if t['ownerName2'].eql?('name') && !t['reason'].eql?('Starter fund')
    uniqueKey = t['ownerID1'].to_s + t['date']
    if !Payment.exists?(:unique_payment_key => uniqueKey)
      p = Payment.new
      p.owner_id = t['ownerID1']
      p.owner_name = t['ownerName1']
      p.unique_payment_key = uniqueKey
      p.amount = t['amount']
      p.reason = t['reason']
      p.save
    end
  end
end
```

Sorry, the error is `error: can't convert String into Integer online line 42` which is

```
if t['ownerName2'].eql?('name') && !t['reason'].eql?('Starter fund')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you can fix your immediate problem by using `//row` instead of `row`, assuming you want row elements at any depth.

However, HTTParty parses your response for you, so it's a bit redundant use it just to post a page, if you're going to parse it a different way.

Comment: alright, the reason I'm trying to use nokogiri is for some reason I get an error with the hash that is returned when I try to loop through it.  I think it was cant convert integer to string. I've read that it's because of the array index.

Comment: Which is really strange because the original code I had works fine with a different Eve Online account character, but when I use the new character I receive that error.

Comment: Thanks man. I did it your way and it worked fine without error. It can be redundant, but w/e. Thanks again.